# Multiple colab sessions working in the same google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-colaboratory

I'm using Google Colab and Google sheets to automate some stuff. Would the process be faster if I split the script into parts that can run in multiple colab sessions (e.g. session 1 deals with steps 1-100, while session 2 deals with steps 101-200 in parallel) or can the sheets interface only handle one inquiry at a time?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Tested this for myself. Results were:

1 session did 1,15 iterations per minute
3 sessions did 1,7 (0,48 + 0,65 + 0,57) iterations per minute

I have noticed that performance depends on some limitations from Google that varies, so I cannot know for sure if it is correct until I've done more tests. First test looks promising though.